# How to remove locally stored Exchange emails?

Tags: email, ms-office, exchange

VIP in company who uses several people's mail boxes purchased Mac Air. Outlook 2011 by default insists on locally storing everything.

50k+ items, plus attachments later the HDD is full. I've set the accounts to download headers only, but the HDD is still full. How do I remove the locally stored mail, because it's still on the exchange server where it belongs?

The computer is so full it can't really do anything anymore and I can only come to this Office once before Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2011 cannot disable storing the email locally. Your best alternative would be to access the email using Outlook Web Access (if it is enabled).

Comment: Yes, but you can ask Outlook to only download email headers which would have been the preventative measure. Just need to find out how to remove the data that's stored locally.